# Issue with openssl aes-128 encryption for Apple's HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ios, encryption, openssl, aes, http-live-streaming

We are using `openssl aes-128 encryption` for streaming media on `HLS video streaming` for Apple.

Below is the command used for the `aes-128 encryption`

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -salt -k <HEXKey> -iv <HEXIV> -in <INFILE> -out <OUTFILE>
```

And below in my `Playlist / Index` File being used for hls streaming.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-VERSION:2
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://xxx.xxxx.xxx/key.txt",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10,
http://xxx.xxxx.xxx/encry.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Where , `key.txt` contains the hex key as of form `0x00000000000000000000000000000000`.

But this is not working and not playing media on `IOS` device. provides error as `This movie could not be played`

I am not sure , what is wrong in it. Is this issue of `encryption method` or `playlist file`

Please help me. I'll Appreciate.

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT :**

I Felt , below few information, may help if anything wrong in that.

Below is command I use for creating hex `key` and `IV`

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -k String@MyKey -P -md sha1
```

Please help me if anything wrong with it.

now my playlist file parsing fine with `Media Stream Validator` , but while validating media it gives below error.

```
unable to parse segment due to encryption
```

Please help anybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is actually with the file 'key.txt'. The HLS specs say that the URI attribute within the #EXT-X-KEY tag must point to a file with an array of the 16 octets in binary format, not the hex string that you are providing.

For more info see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-10#section-5

Comment: yes @oscahie , i had get the issue resolved. :) , and when i came here to update my post , so it can be useful if some other done the same mistake. i got the correct answer... for which i was waiting from a week :) . and thanks again for confirmation.

Comment: OMG Thank you. '*%$&

Answer (score 2):

Well , Actual issue was the `key.txt` file , which i just found before few hours. 
My `key.txt` , should not contain the `hexkey` , but should contain `16bytes` key.

so my key creation method and using it in both encryption method and `playlist` file , was the wrong step.

Below are the changes I made , and its start working.

command for creation of key

```
openssl rand -base64 12
```

now I added this key in the key.txt file , and my index.m3u8 file , point to this key file.

comnand for encryption , used hexdump using c# of above key in `<hex-key>`

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in <infile> -out <outfile> -p -nosalt -iv <hex-iv>  -K <hex-key>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your EXT-X-KEY syntax is wrong:

Before the key uri should be **URI** instead of **Key**.

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://xxx.xxxx.xxx/key.txt",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks @vipw, for your reply. But it is not working with `URI` as well. :( , do you think , is there any other flows in that. like in `encryption method` , or in `index file` ?

Comment: or if there can be any other aspects which we should watch out ,which may fails it to work??

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but ONLY on IOS device (browser like chromecast, firefox... are ok)
this is my playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxx/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx_enc.key",IV=0x000000000000000000
#EXTINF:3.840000,
xxx_480p_000.ts
#EXTINF:1.440000,
xxx_480p_001.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I checked with the safari web inspector and I can't understand, the key is downloaded correctly but stops when it downloads the first segment

someone with the same problem?

[image]